# comma separated thousand NSString stringWithFormat

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring, stringwithformat

Is it possible to display 1000.99 as 1,000.99 using

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"£%0.2f", 1000.99]
```

Please guide me if I am not on the right track to achieve this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

It can handle all your numeric formatting needs and do so in an automatically localized fashion, when used correctly (since currencies around the world are often written with different punctuation & formatting).

In particular, check out the number formatting guide linked to at the top of the class documentation

Comment: Can you please provide with a simple example? Thanks

Comment: @bbum: here is the iPhone specific documentation http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: +1 `NSNumberFormatter` is definitely the correct way to do this.

Comment: Thanks guys. NSNumberFormatter is deninitely the right answer. I have managed to figure out my solution from documentation before Chris Gummer answer (His answer is exactly the way you should do it) that's why I am marking bbum's asnwer. Once again thank you all and hope it would save some ones time.

Answer (score 36):

Using NSNumberFormatter:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSString *numberAsString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 1000.99]];
NSLog(@"%@", numberAsString);
```